# Error in the LogCat: Error to popular data org.json.JSONException: value i>>? of tpe java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, http

I'm trying to convert a String [] json to a query on an external server and display in a listview

```
public class ConectPhp extends ListActivity {

public static InputStream inpString = null;
String result = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametros = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DATA", "2011-11-05"));



    try{


        HttpClient httpcliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.254.254/mobile/ConexaoWcrm.php/");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametros));
        HttpResponse response = httpcliente.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        inpString = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error to conect a "+e.toString());
    }
```

//convert a return in string

```
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpString, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");

        }
        inpString.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error to convert result"+e.toString());
    }
```

//Here will pass the data to json, but not sure how to do it, then store in the listview.

```
try{            
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        String[] clientes = new String[jArray.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            clientes[i]=json_data.getString("clientnome");
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clientes));
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error popular data "+e.toString());
            }
```

I'm new, and already with this difficult project, if they have any tips to give me will also be accepted, must list certain data bank for external listview.

Comment: if you want to add new thing to your question, you can edit that. code written in comments in not readable...

Comment: but where is Line 31? No one will count number of lines in your code... put some indicator mark at that line

Comment: I put a comment separating the code and indicating where there is probably a conversion error. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below for the string representation which you have posted:-

e.g, your jsonArray is posted at key "array", use following code to retrieve JSONArray from it:-

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);//only if result is a JSONObject else get to the base of JSONObject.
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("array");//I suppose that "array" is the key at for your sample array you have given
//now you can run with your all other code

for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    clientes[i]=json_data.getString("clientnome");
}

this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clientes));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("log_tag","Error popular data "+e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Impart my question, please look where I try to convert, and help me that way.

Comment: Can you give me a sample string, which you are converting in JSONArray, I will post code accordingly.

Comment: What is a sample string? I speak Portuguese, sorry. And I did not understand this expression. Would be this:   [{"clientcod":"635","clientnome":"LEDWARE","solucpropcod":null,"statuscod":"1","origemcod":"1","expecnegcod":null,"faturamcod":null,"satisfaccod":null,"clientencmensal":null,"funcioqtdecod":null,"indicacaocod":null,"clientend":null,"clientendnro":"34","clientendcompl":null,"cidadecod":"1","estadocod":null,"clientcep":null,"clientendbairro":null,"clientsite":null,"clientfoto":null,"clientcrm":null,"clientobs":null,"clientrede":null,"red_cod":null,"clientusecad":null}]

Comment: It's my return of PHP.

Comment: Apologies for late in reply, was on way to home. :)

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
        String[] strings = new String[array.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object object = array.get(i);
            if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
                strings[i] = jsonObject.getString("clientnome");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It was not that. I'm starting to think the error is here:  

'BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpString, "utf-8"), 8);'